# Install adwords Api for python - 'Given yaml file, %s, could not be opened.' % path)'

Tags: python-2.7, api, google-ads-api, oauth-2.0

I try install the adwords api for python following the steps of this reference guide : https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/wiki/API-access-using-own-credentials-(installed-application-flow)#step-2---setting-up-the-client-library

Everything is okay, but in the last step(6), I have one problem.

I try run the code:

```
from googleads import adwords
# Initialize the AdWords client.
adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()
```

And Error is:

```
> >pythonw -u "teste_adwords_api.py" Traceback (most recent call last):   File "teste_adwords_api.py", line 3, in <module>
>     adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()   File "C:\Users\Flávio\Google Drive\BI Caiçara\Python\googleads\adwords.py",
> line 243, in LoadFromStorage
>     cls._OPTIONAL_INIT_VALUES))   File "C:\Users\Flávio\Google Drive\BI Caiçara\Python\googleads\common.py", line 128, in
> LoadFromStorage
>     'Given yaml file, %s, could not be opened.' % path) googleads.errors.GoogleAdsValueError: Given yaml file,
> C:\Users\Flávio\googleads.yaml, could not be opened.
```

My googleads.yaml is:

```
  adwords:
  client_id: xxxxxxx
  client_secret: xxxxxx
  refresh_token: xxxxxx
```

Where xxxx is my passwords keys

I can't understand what problem in my install process.

Answer (score 9):

Had faced similar problem.
By default it searchs for the googleads.yaml file in the home directory, you can point it to your location while creating your AdWords client, e.g.,

```
adwords_client = AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage("full_path_to_your_googleads.yaml")
```

eg:

`adwords_client=AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage(""C:\\MacUSer\\Documents\\googleads.yaml")`

Hope this solves it.

Answer (score 0):

does the yaml file exist in C:\Users\Flávio\ or another path? I was getting the same error before copying the yaml file to the Users\.<